# How can I log the callstack with JCL without using raise exception

Tags: delphi, callstack, jedi-code-library

**Background**

We have a problem that sometimes the grid in Devexpress raise exception 
"Raised EConvertError: Cannot assign a nil to a TFont".

But to trace the real cause of this we have changed Font in cxEdit to be a public property instead with a get and set method. Here I want to log the callstack.

**My question**

Normally JCL is used to log callstacks when exceptions appear. But how can I log the callstack without using raise exception and show a dialog for the user about this ?

I have found the lines:

```
var
  GlobalStackList: TJclGlobalStackList;
```

in JclDebug but I fail to use it. If someone have a example how to get the callstack I would be happy.

Regards Roland Bengtsson

Comment: Not a full duplicate, but you need the same info as answered under [Need a way to periodically log the call stack/stack trace for EVERY method/procedure/function called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326980/need-a-way-to-periodically-log-the-call-stack-stack-trace-for-every-method-proced)

Comment: This is not a exact duplicate of another question, it's specific to JCL.   The other question mentioned ended up wanting a call trace and not a call stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326980/need-a-way-to-periodically-log-the-call-stack-stack-trace-for-every-method-proced/2337111#2337111) shows how to do it with JCL by calling JclCreateStackList.