# How can I generate a reverse call tree for a Delphi project?

Tags: delphi, metrics, static-code-analysis

Is there a way to quickly search for the complete list of code paths to one particular function in my project, in order to find out whether some certain upper-lever function calls it, either directly or indirectly? For example, some possible output to determine whether `MyLowLevelFunction` is reachable from `TargetFunction`:

**Code path 1**

```
ModuleA2.TopLevelFunction
|--ModuleA1.SomeFunction
|----Utility.MyLowLevelFunction
```

**Code path 2**

```
ModuleB2.TopLevelFunction
|--TargetModule.TargetFunction <-- This calls MyLowLevelFunction indirectly
|----ModuleB1.SomeFunction
|------Utility.MyLowLevelFunction
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display the call stack in a Delphi Win32 application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258727/display-the-call-stack-in-a-delphi-win32-application) or [Need a way to periodically log the call stack/stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326980/need-a-way-to-periodically-log-the-call-stack-stack-trace-for-every-method-proced)

Comment: I might be wrong on the dupe.   Are you looking for a static analysis of the code or are you looking for something at runtime?

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. This is about a reverse call tree report  (not a call stack), usually done via static analysis although I suppose you could do it with a sampling profiler.

Comment: This question is totally unclear to me. Perhaps if you used examples that were more distinctly separate (eg., something more differential than `ModuleA` and `ModuleD`) it would be more clear. (A single final letter difference makes it hard to tell them apart, especially when cluttered with `---------------------------`)

Comment: The difference between a stack value (a single call tree) and a reverse call tree, is that a reverse call tree is like a matrix product of all possible forward call trees.

Comment: Hi Robert Love,  thanks for providing the dups. And yes, I am looking for a static-code-analysis.

Comment: Hi Ken White, thanks for the advice. I have refined it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pascal analyzer by Peganza has a [Reverse call tree](http://www.peganza.com/PALHelp/reverse_call_tree_report.htm) report. I am a customer and very happy with it, although I have never used that particular type of report, preferring a simple [cross-ref report](http://www.peganza.com/PALHelp/index.html?cross_reference_report.htm) instead, which it also has.

As an interesting side-note static analysis tools will fail to find calls that are indirect, such as via an event callback.

Comment: Hi Warren, it is so lucky to get the answer from a user of Pascal Analyzer like you:) I have downloaded the evaluation edition of Pascal Analyzer. However the evaluation edition does not contain the feature "Reverse call tree report" nor "cross-ref report". I was wondering whether it can limit the reporting to the particular function? The reason that I ask so is that the generated "call tree report" is a text file around hundreds of MB which makes hard to search. Thank you~

Comment: Jim: That's the basic problem with most of the reports. I wrote a simple utility in Delphi to filter the output of the reports to contain what I want, because most of the reports don't contain what I want.    Further, if your project uses runtime packages, it seems necessary to build a monolithic (no packages) project,  even if you never build it, to get all the units of a package-based solution to be included in a single analysis.  There are workarounds for these limitations.

Comment: Warren: Thanks for the answer! It makes clear now that what the limitation this software has. I guess I will finally purchase it and write a helper program then. Accepted your solution~

Comment: I am unable to generate the build dependency tree by the evaluation version :(