# how to determine which event calls procedure in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a procedure named XYZ(sender:TObject) in delphi. There is one button on my form.

```
Button.onclick:= xyz;
Button.OnExit:= xyz;
```

Both the events calls the same procedure. I want to determine in procedure XYZ, which event calls this(onclick or onexit) and according to that proceed with coding. 
How to determine which event gets fired? thanks

Comment: If you have such needs, probably you have too much code in xyz. You should split it, in x, y e z. Probably OnClick will call x, OnExit will call y, and both will call z.

Comment: The more general question is: How can I get a "call stack" in Delphi? - see this question [Need a way to periodically log the call stack/stack trace for EVERY method/procedure/function called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326980/need-a-way-to-periodically-log-the-call-stack-stack-trace-for-every-method-proce)

Comment: @mjn That wouldn't really help here. Surely you don't won't to encode VCL private implementation details into VCL client code?

Comment: @David of course your answer is the way to go - call stack parsing would be the least acceptable solution, I would not dare posting it as an answer ;)

Comment: This sound like broken logic of code reuse. Call stack is more debugging tool rather than design tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't get hold of that information by fair means. The solution is to use two separate top-level event handlers which in turn can call another method passing a parameter identifying which event is being handled.

```
type
  TButtonEventType = (beOnClick, beOnExit);

procedure TMyForm.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HandleButtenEvent(beOnClick);
end;

procedure TMyForm.ButtonExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HandleButtenEvent(beOnExit);
end;

procedure TMyForm.HandleButtonEvent(EventType: TButtonEventType);
begin
  //use EventType to decide how to handle this
end;
```

Comment: is it possible to get that information in same procedure without using another parameter?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand that question.

Comment: can we get event information like which event fired? Just want to know.

Comment: No you can't. That's covered by the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: +1. It's worth pointing out that you could also pass Sender as a parameter, then you'd be able to use this trick on multiple buttons. Say you have 10 buttons and you wanted to be able to handle them all individually (such as maybe modifying captions/icons/etc.) within HandleButtonEvent.  You would be able to assign all of their click and exit to the two ButtonClick and ButtonExit routines above, without having to replicate all of them.  Obviously, this is only useful if there is a need to handle multiple buttons!